# How to load sound files in combination with dynamic text?

Tags: javascript

In the following example I try with a `next-button` that changes the text next to the `radio-buttons` also to load the corresponding audio files.

The sound later corresponds to a question. The user answers with the `radio-button` and clicks`Next`. The next question should be played and at the same time the answers next to the `radio-buttons` change. The selection of the answers `(radio-buttons)` should be transferred to an external script in a second step.

At the moment, the dynamic lyrics work well, but the sound can not yet be loaded properly to match the text array. `clip1 to arr1, clip2 to arr2 and clip3 to arr3`

Does anyone have a better solution for that? Many Thanks

```js
//////////Text Array1//////////
 
var arr1 = [
 "Argument arr1,1",
 "Argument arr1,2",
 "Argument arr1,3",
 "Argument arr1,4",
];

var i1 = -1;
 
function nextItem1() {  
 i1 = i1 + 1; // increase i by one 
 i1 = i1 % arr1.length 
  
  return arr1[i1] 
}

function prevItem1() {
 if (i1 === 0) { // i would become 0
    i1 = arr1.length   
}
 
 i1 = i1 - 1; // decrease by one
 return arr1[i1]; 
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () {  
 document.getElementById.textContent = arr1[0]; // initial value  
 document.getElementById('prev_button').addEventListener( 
  'click', // we want to listen for a click   
  function (e) { // the e here is the event itself
   document.getElementById('arr1').textContent = prevItem1();    
 }   
);
    
 document.getElementById('next_button').addEventListener(
  'click', // we want to listen for a click
  function (e) { // the e here is the event itself
   document.getElementById('arr1').textContent = nextItem1();
      //document.querySelector('#clip1').click;
  }
 );
});
 
//////////Text Array2//////////

var arr2 = [
 "Argument arr2,1",
 "Argument arr2,2",
 "Argument arr2,3",
 "Argument arr2,4",
];
 
var i2 = -1;

function nextItem2() {    
 i2 = i2 + 1;    
 i2 = i2 % arr2.length
  
  return arr2[i2]; 
}

function prevItem2() {
   if (i2 === 0) { // i would become 0
   i2 = arr2.length  
}
   i2 = i2 - 1; // decrease by one
   return arr2[i2]; 
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () { 
 document.getElementById.textContent = arr2[0]; // initial value 
 document.getElementById('prev_button').addEventListener( 
  'click', // we want to listen for a click
  function (e) { // the e here is the event itself
   document.getElementById('arr2').textContent = prevItem2();   
 }
);
    
document.getElementById('next_button').addEventListener(
  'click', // we want to listen for a click
  function (e) { // the e here is the event itself
   document.getElementById('arr2').textContent = nextItem2();    
  }
 );
});
 
//////////Text Array3//////////
 
var arr3 = [
 "Argument arr3,1",
 "Argument arr3,2",
 "Argument arr3,3",
 "Argument arr3,4",
];
 
var i3 = -1;

function nextItem3() {    
 i3 = i3 + 1;    
 i3 = i3 % arr3.length
  
  return arr3[i3]; 
}

function prevItem3() {
  if (i3 === 0) { // i would become 0
  i3 = arr3.length  
}
  i3 = i3 - 1; // decrease by one
  return arr3[i3]; 
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () { 
 document.getElementById.textContent = arr3[0]; // initial value 
 document.getElementById('prev_button').addEventListener( 
  'click', // we want to listen for a click
  function (e) { // the e here is the event itself
   document.getElementById('arr3').textContent = prevItem3();   
 }
);
    
document.getElementById('next_button').addEventListener(
  'click', // we want to listen for a click
  function (e) { // the e here is the event itself
   document.getElementById('arr3').textContent = nextItem3();   
  }
 );
});
  
//////////Load Sound Clips//////////
  
var listener = new THREE.AudioListener(); 
var audioLoader = new THREE.AudioLoader();
 
var clip1 = document.querySelector('#clip1');
    clip1.addEventListener('click', function () {
    loadClip('https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/sounds/358232_j_s_song.mp3');    
    });

var clip2 = document.querySelector('#clip2');
    clip2.addEventListener('click', function () {
    loadClip('https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/sounds/376737_Skullbeatz___Bad_Cat_Maste.mp3');
    });
 
var clip3 = document.querySelector('#clip3');
    clip3.addEventListener('click', function () {
    loadClip('https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/sounds/358232_j_s_song.mp3');
    });
     
//////////End Sound Clips//////////
 
  
var audioLoaded = false,    
    result 
 
function loadClip( audioUrl ) {
    audioLoaded = false 
 
    console.log(`\nLoading sound...`);  
    audioLoader.load( audioUrl, function( buffer ) {
    sound = new THREE.PositionalAudio( listener );     
    sound.setBuffer( buffer );
    sound.setRefDistance( 20 );
    sound.setLoop(false);
    sound.setVolume(5);
    console.log(`\nAudio finished loading!`);
    audioLoaded = true       
    }); 
 
play.onclick = function playClip() {
    console.log( `\nplayClip()` );
    play.style.background = "#92ddb8";   
   
    reset.disabled = false;
    play.disabled = true;
    paused.disabled = false;
      
    sound.play();   
    }

reset.onclick = function resetClip() {  
    console.log( `\nresetClip()` );    
    play.style.background = "";
    play.style.color = "";      
      
    stop.disabled = true;
    play.disabled = false;
    paused.disabled = false;
      
    sound.stop()
    document.getElementById('radio1').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('radio2').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('radio3').checked = false;
    console.clear()
}
   
paused.onclick = function pausedClip() {  
    console.log( `\npausedClip()` );    
    play.style.background = "";
    play.style.color = "";  

    stop.disabled = false;
    play.disabled = false;
    paused.disabled = true;
      
    sound.pause();
}
}
```

```css
#arr1 {
 font-family:Arial,sans-serif; 
 font-size: 1em; 
 color:black;
 margin-top: -20px;
 margin-left: 30px;
 }

#arr2 {
 font-family:Arial,sans-serif; 
 font-size: 1em; 
 color:black;
 margin-top: -20px;
 margin-left: 30px;
 }

#arr3 {
 font-family:Arial,sans-serif; 
 font-size: 1em; 
 color:black;
 margin-top: -20px;
 margin-left: 30px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="myCheckbox" autocomplete="off" onclick="myCheckbox"/>
<p id="arr1">load audio 1 for test</p>  
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="myCheckbox" autocomplete="off" onclick="myCheckbox"/>
<p id="arr2">load audio 2 for test</p>
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="myCheckbox" autocomplete="off" onclick="myCheckbox"/>
<p id="arr3">load audio 3 for test</p> 

<button id="play" class="play">Play</button>
<button id="paused" class="paused">Pause</button>
<button id="reset" class="reset">Reset</button>

<input type="button" id="prev_button" value="<< Prev" onclick="prev_button">
<input type="button" id="next_button" value="Next >>" onclick="next_button">

<p id="clip1"></p>
<p id="clip2"></p>
<p id="clip3"></p>
```