# How can dynamic text per array be displayed?

Tags: javascript

By pressing the `Next-Button` the text should change dynamically. I use arrays for that. Now the order is not correct.

In the following example I try to display the text per array, at the moment this is still wrong. The text should look like this:

`Argument arr1,1
 Argument arr1,2
 Argument arr1,3`

After pressing the `Next-Button` the next array should be loaded. That should then look like this:

`Argument arr2,1
 Argument arr2,2
 Argument arr2,3`

Does anyone have a solution for that? Thank you.

```js
//////////Text Array1//////////
 
var arr1 = [
 "Argument arr1,1",
 "Argument arr1,2",
 "Argument arr1,3",
 "Argument arr1,4",
];

var i1 = -1;
 
function nextItem1() {  
 i1 = i1 + 1;  
 i1 = i1 % arr1.length 
  
  return arr1[i1] 
}

function prevItem1() {
 if (i1 === 0) { 
    i1 = arr1.length   
}
 
 i1 = i1 - 1; 
 return arr1[i1]; 
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () {  
 document.getElementById.textContent = arr1[0];  
 document.getElementById('prev_button').addEventListener( 
  'click',   
  function (e) { 
   document.getElementById('arr1').textContent = prevItem1();    
 }   
);
    
 document.getElementById('next_button').addEventListener(
  'click', 
  function (e) { 
   document.getElementById('arr1').textContent = nextItem1();      
  }
 );
});
 
//////////Text Array2//////////

var arr2 = [
 "Argument arr2,1",
 "Argument arr2,2",
 "Argument arr2,3",
 "Argument arr2,4",
];
 
var i2 = -1;

function nextItem2() {    
 i2 = i2 + 1;    
 i2 = i2 % arr2.length
  
  return arr2[i2]; 
}

function prevItem2() {
   if (i2 === 0) { 
   i2 = arr2.length  
}
   i2 = i2 - 1; 
   return arr2[i2]; 
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () { 
 document.getElementById.textContent = arr2[0]; 
 document.getElementById('prev_button').addEventListener( 
  'click', 
  function (e) { 
   document.getElementById('arr2').textContent = prevItem2();   
 }
);
    
document.getElementById('next_button').addEventListener(
  'click', 
  function (e) { 
   document.getElementById('arr2').textContent = nextItem2();    
  }
 );
});
 
//////////Text Array3//////////
 
var arr3 = [
 "Argument arr3,1",
 "Argument arr3,2",
 "Argument arr3,3",
 "Argument arr3,4",
];
 
var i3 = -1;

function nextItem3() {    
 i3 = i3 + 1;    
 i3 = i3 % arr3.length
  
  return arr3[i3]; 
}

function prevItem3() {
  if (i3 === 0) { 
  i3 = arr3.length  
}
  i3 = i3 - 1; 
  return arr3[i3]; 
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () { 
 document.getElementById.textContent = arr3[0];  
 document.getElementById('prev_button').addEventListener( 
  'click', 
  function (e) { 
   document.getElementById('arr3').textContent = prevItem3();   
 }
);
    
document.getElementById('next_button').addEventListener(
  'click', 
  function (e) { 
   document.getElementById('arr3').textContent = nextItem3();   
  }
 );
});
```

```css
#arr1 {
 font-family:Arial,sans-serif; 
 font-size: 1em; 
 color:black;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

#arr2 {
 font-family:Arial,sans-serif; 
 font-size: 1em; 
 color:black;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 }

#arr3 {
 font-family:Arial,sans-serif; 
 font-size: 1em; 
 color:black;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<p id="arr1">Test Text</p>
<p id="arr2">Test Text</p>
<p id="arr3">Test Text</p>

<input type="button" id="prev_button" value="<< Prev" onclick="prev_button">
<input type="button" id="next_button" value="Next >>" onclick="next_button">
```

Comment: Instead of having 3 seperate click events that each updates one field with its own array, try reversing it. One click event that updates all 3 fields with the current array.

Comment: ***@Shilly*** Thank you for your response. I tried that, but I always get an indefinable text mixture. Maybe you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kinda had to restructure the code. Do me a favor, and keep reading tutorials, watch videos, while you learn. Certain things like `i3 = i3 + 1; i3 = i3 % arr3.length` instead of using the index looks strange to me.

```js
// You can simplify this code alot, since basically you have exactly the same event multiple times.
// a single variable to hold the index of our active array.
var currentArray = 0;
// We can put all our arrays into an array as well, so that we can add or remove arrays without actually having to write `var arr4 = [];`
var arrays = [
 [ "Argument arr1,1", "Argument arr1,2", "Argument arr1,3", "Argument arr1,4", ],
 [ "Argument arr2,1", "Argument arr2,2", "Argument arr2,3", "Argument arr2,4", ],
 [ "Argument arr3,1", "Argument arr3,2", "Argument arr3,3", "Argument arr3,4", ]
];
// TO change the text, we need the text from 1 array to fill up all 3 of the fields.
var renderArray = function renderArray( ary ) {
 document.querySelector( '#arr1' ).textContent = ary[ 0 ];
 document.querySelector( '#arr2' ).textContent = ary[ 1 ];
 document.querySelector( '#arr3' ).textContent = ary[ 2 ];
};
// Since our active array is just an index, add or subtract 1 from the index, resetting it if the new number doesn't have an array.
var previous = function previous( event ) {
 currentArray -= 1;
 if ( currentArray < 0 ) currentArray = arrays.length - 1;
 renderArray( arrays[ currentArray ] );
};
// The reverse of previous
var next = function next( event ) {
 currentArray += 1;
 if ( currentArray > arrays.length - 1 ) currentArray = 0;
 renderArray( arrays[ currentArray ] );
};
document.querySelector( '#prev_button' ).addEventListener( 'click', previous );
document.querySelector( '#next_button' ).addEventListener( 'click', next );
```

```html
<p id="arr1">Test Text</p>
<p id="arr2">Test Text</p>
<p id="arr3">Test Text</p>
<input type="button" id="prev_button" value="<< Prev">
<input type="button" id="next_button" value="Next >>">
```

Comment: ***@Shilly*** Thank you for the excellent help. In the field of arrays I'm still learning. I have much to do !!

Comment: ***@Shilly*** Together with the arrays I have to load audio files. So with `arr1,1 - arr1,4 the AudioFile1` and with `arr2,1 - 2,4 the AudioFile2` and so on. For this I have to include the following: `document.querySelector ('#clip1'). Click ();`  This works, but the `audiofile1` should only be loaded with the `arr1`. When next would then be the `audiofile2` with `arr2` the result. I can not really get on there yet. Maybe you see a solution immediately?

Comment: Do you use a <audio> tag for it? If so, leave the src of the element empty at first. Make a new function `playAudio()` that will change the src of #clip and call the play() or click() on it., and add it to the `previous()` and `next()` function after `renderArray()` Something like that, haven't tried yet tbh.

Comment: ***@Shilly*** That's a good approach, thanks. The audio example looks like this: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47876182/how-to-load-sound-files-in-combination-with-dynamic-text)